# Put array on a specific object by id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Good morning/afternoon/evening/evening,

The problem is that I have the following structure:

`var array = [ { { id: 0 }, { id: 1 } ]`

And I would like to know how to put an array inside the first object:

The array struct that I am interested in assigning is the following:

`var arr = [ { { name: 0, color: 'black', points: [Array] } ]`

The expected result would look something like this:

[ **{ id: 0, arr: [ { name: 0, color: 'black', points: [Array] } ]
}**, { id: 1 } ]

I have tried several things but none of them worked for me like for example the splice:

`array.splice(pid, 0, arr)` but doesnt work.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the array by the index and assign the value by key like this:

```js
var array = [ { id: 0 }, { id: 1 } ]

array[0].arr = [ { name: 0, color: 'black', points: [] } ]

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your array have a Unexpected token '{'. Assuming it shouldn't be there. You'd have something like this.

```
const array = [ { id: 0 }, { id: 1 } ]
```

You can map the array, and return a different value by the id or index from the current array, something like this:

```
const newArray = array.map((current, index) => {
   if(current.id === 0) {
      return {
      id: current.id,
      color: 'black',
      points: [],
      }
   } 
    return {
      id: current.id,
    }
});
```